# How to find out ejb 2.x vs 3.x code beans

Tags: ejb

I am working on migrating code base which has EJB 2.x as well as 3.x code.

How do I identify EJB 2.x code (session beans, message driven beans).

The code uses session beans with annotations and some beans are also defined in ejb-jar.xml.

I thought these annotated beans would be specific to 3.x code and the ones from ejb-jar.xml file would be 2.x beans , but then I found this class

```
@Stateless
@TransactionManagement(TransactionManagementType.BEAN)
public class ABC implements javax.ejb.SessionBean{
//methods
}
```

3.x beans do not implement javax.ejb.SessionBean right?
Is the above code snippet 2.x or 3.x ejb?

Let me know your thoughts

Answer (score 0):

2.x EJB are required to implement SessionBean
3.x EJB are not required (but can) implement Session Bean

2.x EJB should have a Home interface